# What is the correct code for getting the connecting nodes with constraints in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to get the connecting nodes. The final node should have a type(r) of pobj. How can I specify it with the shortest path?

```
match(c:fdnode{name:'flights'}) 
match(d:fdnode) 
match p = shortestPath((c)-[*..15]-(e)-[r]-(d)) 
where d.name = '700' and type(r) = 'pobj' 
RETURN nodes(p)
```

If I remove r, the code returns desired output. But I need the type(r).

pobj is only for this specific case.I have multiple traversal criteria.

Comment: You're mixing up nodes and relationships. Relationships have types, nodes have labels. Also in your pattern syntax square brackets are for relationships, parenthesis are for nodes, and a variable-length path has to connect nodes, you can't have a connection from `[*..15]` to a relationship. Also if you need to express a connection between nodes in a pattern and you don't care about the relationship between them, you need to use two dashes `--` instead of a single dash. Please fix your query so we can fully understand what you need here.

Comment: I removed the node e. Does it look clean now? In the final query I do not intend to use d.name. Instead it will be type(r). Also is there a way to execute it to get the terminal node?

Comment: Is `r` meant to be a node or a relationship? In any case as stated above you can't connect relationships to relationships, so either `r` should be a node, or you need a node in your pattern between `[*..15]` and `[r]`.

Comment: Regarding this: `I do not intend to use d.name` , do you mean that you're just looking for shortest paths to :fdnodes where the last relationship of the path is a :pobj relationship? If you're not pre-matching to specific `c` and `d` nodes, you shouldn't be using shortestPath(), as otherwise it will match (and give you a cross product) against all :fdnodes and try to find shortest paths to each.

Comment: I am prematching c using graph joins. After that I intend to traverse to different nodes based on specific criteria. I am not prematching d.

Comment: I can use with and keep going to the end. But it is too lengthy and cumbersome. Variable path lengths seems more practical..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query may do what you want. It returns the nodes in the shortest undirected path (of up to length 15) that meets these criteria:

- The first node has the label 'fdnode', and its `name` value is 'flights'.
- The last node has the label 'fdnode', and its `name` value is '700'.
- The last relationship has the type, `pobj`.

  ```
  MATCH p = shortestPath((c:fdnode)-[*..15]-(d:fdnode)) 
  WHERE c.name = 'flights' AND d.name = '700' AND TYPE(LAST(RELATIONSHIPS(p))) = 'pobj'
  RETURN NODES(p);
  ```

*NOTE: The matched path will be "undirected" because this query mimicked your query by not specifying any directionality in the `MATCH` pattern. So, every matched relationship is allowed to be in either direction. If this is not what you intended, you need to explicitly specify the directionality in your pattern.*

Comment: This works. But in the final query I need to eliminate d.name. it gives the following error:  Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed:
The shortest path algorithm does not work when the start and end nodes are the same. 
I have more than one paths that meet the criteria.

Comment: Also works:q = "MATCH p = shortestPath((c:fdnode)-[*..4]-(d:fdnode)) WHERE c.name = 'flights' and d.name in ['noon','700'] and TYPE(LAST(RELATIONSHIPS(p))) = 'pobj' RETURN NODES(p)"
But I need to eliminate d.name.

Comment: One option is to provide variable paths in graph joins. Can you provide the code for the same?

Comment: What do you mean by "eliminate d.name"?

Comment: I will prematch the c node but I don't have the names of d node. I want to travel to d node without explicitly specifying its name. I want to use relations to travel to d node.

Comment: Done. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. This works.

```
match (a:iknode)-[*..10]->(b:iknode)-[r]->(c:iknode) where type(r) =  'pobj' and a.name = 'flights' return c
```

This also works:

```
MATCH p = ((c:fdnode)-[*..4]->(d:fdnode)) 
WHERE c.name = 'flights'  AND TYPE(LAST(RELATIONSHIPS(p))) = 'pobj'
RETURN NODES(p) order by length(p) ;
```